# Undocumented abstract method in android.view.inputmethod.InputMethod

Tags: java, android, ime

I have an input method that I've written for Android that started to misbehave when I recently "upgraded" my Samsung Note 4 to Marshmallow.  After a fair amount of thrashing around I discovered that the periodic crashing of the input method was caused by:

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.view.inputmethod.InputMethod.unMinimizeSoftInput()"

Does anyone know anything about this ridiculous "enhancement" of the input method API?  Googling it turned up absolutely nothing.  By adding the method

```
   public void unMinimizeSoftInput() { }
```

to the appropriate class in my hierarchy I was able to restore normal behavior, but it's extremely annoying and puzzling that I had to go through this rigamarole...